# Error: Too few Argument in multithreaded code

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have been trying to implement a multithreaded program, I already tried <thread.h> and the code worked perfectly; but now I have to use <pthread.h> library due to some college project.
I wrote a long code, but for now the problem i'm struggling with, is about pthread_create function.
So, I just write only a part of the code that I'm asking about:

```
#include<pthread.h>
using namespace std;
void hello() 
{
    cout << "HelloWorld\n";
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p,NULL,hello);
    cout << "Thread created\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
new.cpp:11:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
  pthread_create(&p,NULL,hello);
                         ^~~~~
new.cpp:11:30: error: too few arguments to function ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
  pthread_create(&p,NULL,hello);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
                 from new.cpp:1:
/usr/include/pthread.h:234:12: note: declared here
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that similar questions might be already asked, but I tried their solution as much as I could and none of them worked; Also, I don't want to pass any argument to the specified function.
Don't know what to do now.
Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: You don't have a choice about the function signature. It **must** take a `void *`. You're free to pass null and ignore it.

Comment: Unrelated: Since you are programming in C++, why do you complicate everything by using a platform specific C API like [tag:pthread] when there's a perfectly standardized way to do [threading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) in the standard C++ library?

Comment: @Amin And what is unclear with the compiler messages?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi! well I already mentioned that I used to include <thread> library in my code, but this time I have to use pthread as a college project; otherwise I won't get the score :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, the function that is the entry point for a thread as specified by the third argument to `pthread_create` must accept a `void *` as an argument and return a `void *`.  Your function must conform to that signature.  You're free to ignore the parameter and to just return NULL.

```
void *hello(void *param) 
{
    cout << "HelloWorld\n";
    return NULL;
}
```

Second, `pthread_create` takes a fourth argument of type `void *` which is the argument to the thread function.  Since you're not using the argument, you can pass a null pointer.

```
pthread_create(&p,NULL,hello,NULL);
```

Comment: `void *hello(void *param)` can be `void *hello(void *)` if you want to get rid of the warning about an unused parameter.

Comment: @dbush It works! dunno why I ain't allowed to use <thread> lib instead of pthread, but thank you anyway